# Word for changing from descending to ascending, and back again?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for changing flow from descending to ascending?

I have a bunch of data and it is ordered A-Z, descending. When I press a button, it reverses and is now ordered Z-A, ascending.

It just made me wonder, is there a single word to describe this process of changing from descending to ascending to also back again?

I understand *reverse*, *flip*, *change* or perhaps *invert* would work fine, I just want to know if there's a specific word for this process.

Comment: Did you just reverse the meaning of ascending and descending? Ascending would be A-Z

Comment: Typically, a flow is said to reverse. It is reversed or it reverses.